# Websockets performance problems - packet bundling yields 5fps

Tags: browser, tcp, websocket, faye

I'm using Faye, which uses websockets.

The rate at which my server sends packets is very consistent.  Its average deviation is less than a millisecond.  If I run the client on the same machine, the client's average deviation is pretty close too.  However, when I run the client on another machine, something bad happens when I up the frame rate.

When I emit at 5 frames per second, the other party receives them at about the right rate.  When I increase that to 10 fps, the client will receive one frame in 200ms and the next just 1ms later, like every other packet is bundled with the previous one.  When I increase it to 20fps, most of the packets appear bundled this way: I'll get one in 300ms followed by four or so more in 1ms.  It's as if all I can get is 5fps, and asking for more just sends things in bundles at 5fps.

Is it possible to prevent this bundling and get my packets at a consistent rate?  Is more than 5fps too much to hope for?  Is this a limitation in Faye or Websockets or TCP in general?